# Memcache - Local or Dedicated Server?

Tags: php, memcached, scalability

What are the pros and cons of having memcached running on a seperate server instead of locally?

This is my server setup:
-2 Dedicated Servers (Load Balanced)
-1 Dedicated MySQL Server
-1 Dedicated Memcached Server

Is there any benefit of dropping the Memcached Server and putting the daemon locally on the 2 dedicated servers? Or is that a bad move?

Just wondering if there are any known bottlenecks/how resilient memcached is if a lot of requests are coming from potentially 2 servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dedicated server is on the same LAN, then the connection overhead shouldn't be an issue. In that case, the main consideration is the availability of RAM. Whether you run memcached on one of your existing servers or a new one depends on if one of your existing servers has enough unused RAM to do so. Whatever you dedicate to memcached takes away from what MySQL or other services can use, and takes away from memory available for the OS to cache frequently used/served files.

Comment: App servers often don't need a lot of memory. Depends on the app of course. Furthermore, it's the app that needs the memcache, so putting it locally on the app server removed the network I/O on both sides.